# Getting folder name

Tags: python

I iterate over a bunch of folders and files in the folders, doing this:

```
def get_files_in_directory(directory=rootDirectory):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(directory, topdown='true'):
        print("root %s dirs %s files %s" %(root, dirs, files));
        for file in files:
            ext = os.path.splitext(file)[-1].lower();
            if (ext == '.mod'):
                print(file);
```

When I print the file, I would like to also print the relative name of the dir that contains it.

So if I have

```
C:\\myfolderA\\myFolderB\\myFile.MOD
```

I just get

```
myFolderB
```

I don't want

```
C:\\myFolderA\\myFolderB
```

which of course I can get from the dir variable

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`os.path.relpath()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.relpath):

```
print os.path.relpath(root, directory)
```

where `directory` is the local variable name already present in your function. `os.path.relpath()` makes `root` a path relative to `directory`. Since you started your walk from `directory` that'll be `myFolderB` for a starting point of `directory = "C:\\myfolderA"`

Answer (score 17):

Use `os.path.relpath(".","..")` and you're done.

Answer (score 4):

file_path is the full path to the file.

```
folder_path = os.path.dirname(file_path)
```

folder_path is now the full path to folder containing file.

```
path,folder_name = os.path.split(folder_path)
```

folder_name is now just the name of the folder at the end of folder_path.

```
print folder_name
```

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> os.path.relpath('/myFolderA/myFolderB/myFile.MOD', '/myFolderA')
'myFolderB/myFile.MOD'
```

Answer (score 0):

Experiment with [`os.path.relpath("myFolderA\\myFile.MOD", "c:\\")`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html). `os.path.abspath` might also come in handy.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at David Beazley talk, "Generator Tricks for System Programmers".

Slides and source code from presentation can be found [here](http://www.dabeaz.com/generators/index.html).